# What is the current protection on an iframe site?

Tags: security, iframe, content-security-policy, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

In different site I see different data about what mechanism protects against inserting an iframe.
Tell me, is it possible that these are different levels of protection or are some of these outdated mechanisms?

1. Same-origin policy prohibits opening an iframe of another domain
2. At the same time, there is a Content-Security-Policy with the frame-ancestors directive
3. And there is also X-Frame-Options: DENY

Comment: Are you trying to prevent iframes on your website, or prevent other websites from framing yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), by itself, doesn't prevent you from framing a document from another origin.

[`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) and [CSP's `frame-ancestors` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) overlap as defences against cross-origin framing. Only the former is supported in old browsers, though. However, the latter is much more flexible. Also, in case both are present in a response, [`frame-ancestors` takes precedence over `X-Frame-Options`](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options) in supporting browsers.

Finally, don't forget that you can [sandbox an iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) in order to further isolate the framing document from the framed document.

Comment: 1. But CORS blocking the iframe?

Comment: CORS blocks nothing and has nothing to do with iframes. Instead, you can use CORS to selectively lift some of the restrictions of the Same-Origin Policy.